# Как задать команду из ViewModel на событие DropDownOpened элемента ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, binding, xaml

Вот пробовал так:

```
    <ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding IpList}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIp , Mode=TwoWay}"
               IsEnabled ="{Binding IsEnabled}"
               DropDownOpened = "{Binding HintCommand}">
```

Вот что получил:

> DropDownOpened="{Binding HintCommand}" is not valid. '{Binding HintCommand}' is not a valid event handler method name. Only instance methods on the generated or code-behind class are valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Использовать Microsoft.Expression.Interactivity
инфа: [MVVM invoking command on attached event](http://joyfulwpf.blogspot.com/2009/05/mvvm-invoking-command-on-attached-event.html)
примерно так:

```
 <ComboBox Grid.Column="1" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding IpList}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIp , Mode=TwoWay}"
               IsEnabled ="{Binding IsEnabled}">

         <interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
              <interactivity:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                     <!--<cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding MyCommand}" />-->
              </interactivity:EventTrigger>
          </interactivity:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ComboBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

Кому будет интересно:

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"

<ComboBox  Grid.Column="1" 
               ItemsSource="{Binding IpList}"
               SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedIp , Mode=TwoWay}"
               IsEnabled ="{Binding IsEnabled}">

        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="DropDownOpened">
                <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding GetInterfacesCommand}"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    </ComboBox>
```

Нужно добавить в рефнренсы microsoft.expression.interactivity.dll